# Arduino pro mini resetting itself

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, drone, capacitors

[image]I am working on a brushed motor quadcopter using Arduino pro mini.

Every time I try to throttle, the Arduino gets reset by itself (motors start to spin but they will be turned off in 2 sec). I have added a `1000uf` capacitor (tried up to `3300uf`) to the input of Arduino `VCC` and `GND`. But still having the same issue.

Comment: Please show a wiring diagram or schematic of your setup

Comment: Do you have suppression capacitors on your motors?

Comment: What battery are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.7V 650mAH (Lithium Polymer) Lipo Rechargeable Battery for Drone.
 
Specifications
Battery model: KP 802540
Nominal voltage: 3.7V
Charging voltage: 4.2V
Nominal capacity: 650mAh
Operating temperature: -10 to 55°C
Discharging cut-off voltage: 3.2V
Charging current: 1C (max)
Discharge current: 15C (max)
Dimension: 43mm(L) x 25mm(W) x 8mm(H)
Weight: 10g..

Comment: and iam using 8520 Colorless Motor

Comment: @chrisl i have added schematic

Comment: Sounds like a power issue. Are you using the same battery for the motors and Arduino? If yes, Can you try a different battery/power source for arduino?

Comment: Yes I am using the same battery.

Comment: Now Iam planning to use 1200mah with 20C discharge current, so that i get 6A (20*1.2 /4) per motor (However my motor 8520 stall current is 5.3A) is that fine?

Comment: Before replacing the batteries, You can try a different battery just for Arduino and see if it still resets. Because more batteries = more weight.

Comment: I have also tried to connecting directly to computer(without battery) while calibration..it has resets. @AjithGopi

Comment: Can you try replacing the motors with LEDs and check if it resets? If it works, only connect one motor at first and see what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123136/discussion-between-ajithmahi07-and-ajith-gopi).